# Changing bundle id on urban airship portal

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I was having some issue with urban airship not sending notifications to my production app and after more debugging, it seems that app on my urban airship portal has the wrong app bundle id. However I can't find any way to change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it's read from the certificate's .p12 that you upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use token-based authentication. In such case you set the bundle ID manually. And you will always see the first bundle ID that was read from the certificate in **Settings** -> **APIs & Integrations** -> **Airship API**, probably it's a bug.